# how-to pass the reference of the current instance in C#

Tags: c#, reference

e.g. something like ( ref this ) which does not work ... E.g. this fails:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CopyOfThis
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            View objView = new View();
            objView.Boo();
            objView.ShowMsg("The objView.StrVal is " + objView.StrVal);
            Console.Read();
        }
    } //eof Program


    class View
    {
        private string strVal;
        public string StrVal
        {
            get { return strVal; }
            set { strVal = value; } 

        }
        public void Boo()
        {
            Controller objController = new Controller(ref this);
        }

        public void ShowMsg ( string msg ) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg); 
        }


    } //eof class 

    class Controller
    {
        View View { get; set; } 
        public Controller(View objView)
        {
            this.View = objView;
            this.LoadData();
        }

        public void LoadData()
        {
            this.View.StrVal = "newData";
            this.View.ShowMsg("the loaded data is" + this.View.StrVal); 
        }
    } //eof class 

    class Model
    { 

    } //eof class 
} //eof namespace
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more information? An example of what you need it for in your application might make it easier for someone to answer it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`this` is already a reference. Code like

```
DoSomethingWith(this);
```

is passing the reference to the current object to the method `DoSomethingWith`.

Comment: I *think* the OP might be wanting to pass a copy of the reference, hence the "(ref this)" bit of the quesiton. Could be wrong though, as not really clear.

Comment: And of course, if the method is on the same object you don't need to pass it anyway, just use this in the method.

Comment: Jupp. I will revise accordingly when OP provides us with more background.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Given your edited code example, you don't need to pass `ref this` since as the accepted answer states - this is already a reference.

you can't pass the `this` reference by reference because it is constant; passing it by ref would allow it to be changed - which is nonsense as far as C# is concerned.

The closest you can get is to do:

```
var this2 = this;
foo(ref this2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the variable passed as `ref` should be initialized before.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method like this:

```
void Foo(ref Bar value) {
  // bla bla
}
```

You can call it from a Bar object by creating a temporary variable like this

```
var temp = this;
foo.Foo(ref temp);
```